# How to loop over N columns when N is a number the user entered? VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if it's possible to ask the user a number (I know how to do this) and then, beginning with let's say G column, looping over each column depending on the number the user entered?

Example:

User Input = 4

```
   G       H       I       J       ...
Item_G1 Item_H1 Item_I1 Item_J1 Item_...n1
Item_G2 Item_H2 Item_I2 Item_J2 Item_...n2
Item_G3 Item_H3 Item_I3 Item_J3 Item_...n3
Item_G4 Item_H4 Item_I4 Item_J4 Item_...n4
```

Meaning, Input a number and then depending on the number looping also on that letter+the number of letters. So, After it's done with all the G's items looping over the H's items, and so on... N numbers could be the input. I saw something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985060/excel-vba-loop-on-columns) but I don't know how a number fits there (new to VBA). Is it possible to add a number to G and suddenly being in F?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I really appreciate you guys answers but I ended up doing something like this. [These](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/737091-possible-loop-over-n-columns-when-n-number-user-entered.html) guys helped me get here.

```
           firstSite = 7 'Primer Sitio
    cantidad_sitios = InputBox("Por Favor ingrese cantidad de sitios en Lista de Materiales: ", "Cantidad de Sitios")
    For i = firstSite To (cantidad_sitios - 1) + firstSite
       ' Getting Site Name & Code
        SiteName = MaterialListSheet.Range(Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1) & "4").Value
        SiteCode = MaterialListSheet.Range(Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1) & "3").Value

        'loop here
   Next i
```

Comment: This is still ***MUCH*** slower AND resource heavier then my solution. As you are still looping every single cell, again mine does not. Also why are you not just saying `SiteName = MaterialListSheet.Cells(4, i)` and `SiteCode = MaterialListSheet.Cells(3, i)` ??? If you show how you use the Site variable I can update my answer and then show you how much performance is being lost with your solution.

Comment: My knowledge on VBA is pretty much non-existant, I didn't know you could do that. Edited my answer to delete the "Site" Variable that I'm not using and added code

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
Sub main()


    user_input_rows = InputBox("Input rows to loop")
    user_input_cols = InputBox("Input columns to loop")

    If user_input_rows <> "" And IsNumeric(user_input_rows) And user_input_cols <> "" And IsNumeric(user_input_cols) Then

        For i = 1 To user_input_rows
            For j = 7 To user_input_cols
                Cells(i, j).Value = "Item_" & Split((Cells(i, j).Address), "$")(1) & Split((Cells(i, j).Address), "$")(2)
            Next
        Next

    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to looping over all the values in your range.

```
Dim lngRows As Long
Dim lngColumns As Long
Dim rngStartingCell As Range
Dim rngItems As Range

lngColumns = InputBox("Input Number Of Items")
lngRows = InputBox("How Many Items For Each Item")

Set rngStartingCell = [G1] 'Change to your starting cell
Set rngItems = rngStartingCell.Resize(lngRows, lngColumns)

With rngItems
    .Formula = "=""Item_"" & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),""$"","""")"
    'The Following Line is Optional But it well remove the formula from the cells
    'Leaving only the Desired results
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

But I like to put a wrapper around my code as follows that will increase the performance of your code. And help avoid endless loops if you have worksheet events

```
Sub Sample()
'Save Settings, Then turn them all off
'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
With Application
Dim StartingScreenUpdateing As Boolean
Dim StartingEnabledEvent As Boolean
Dim StartingCalculations As XlCalculation

StartingScreenUpdateing = .ScreenUpdating
StartingEnabledEvent = .EnableEvents
StartingCalculations = .Calculation

    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With
'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Dim lngRows As Long
Dim lngColumns As Long
Dim rngStartingCell As Range
Dim rngItems As Range

lngColumns = InputBox("Input Number Of Items")
lngRows = InputBox("How Many Items For Each Item")

Set rngStartingCell = [G1] 'Change to your starting cell
Set rngItems = rngStartingCell.Resize(lngRows, lngColumns)

With rngItems
    .Formula = "=""Item_"" & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),""$"","""")"
    'The Following Line is Optional But it well remove the formula from the cells
    'Leaving only the Desired results
    .Value = .Value
End With

'Restore starting settings.
'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = StartingScreenUpdateing
    .EnableEvents = StartingEnabledEvent
    .Calculation = StartingCalculations
End With
'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

End Sub
```

Comment: I posted all the code, if you see any improvements please let me know. Your answer seems way better researched than mine