# Run Same VBA Macro Code for more than one Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

My following code runs perfectly, it is just copying and pasting data from one workbook to another workbook called 'summary workbook'. Every workbook corresponds to a gage station in which I am extracting the same cells from all the workbooks onto a 'summary workbook' that contains all the data. I wanted to know if there is a way to repeat the same code for each gage workbook, so I wouldn't have to manually change it? I know I would have to change the workbook it is copying it from as well, or would I have to change that manually as well?

Additional info:

The workbook that I am copying is called "run_10296500.xlsm", and within that workbook I am taking out the data in the sheet called "dashboard". The "summary workbook" is the active workbook, and sheet1 is in this workbook.

The code I have is as follows:

```
Sub Hungry4Gages()

Dim x As Workbook

Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:

Set y = ActiveWorkbook


 Dim LastRow As Long

    For i = 1 To 50
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Grand Total" Then
            Line = i
            Range("A" & i + 1 & ":CS50").Select
            Selection.Clear
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

'FALL

[Class1!E6].Formula = "='C:\Users\dguitron\Documents\Belize and Sam Project\Class 1\[run_10296500.xlsm]dashboard'!E17"
[Class1!E6] = [Class1!E6].Value        

[Class1!E7].Formula = "='C:\Users\dguitron\Documents\Belize and Sam Project\Class 1\[run_10296500.xlsm]dashboard'!E18"
[Class1!E7] = [Class1!E7].Value         

[Class1!E8].Formula = "='C:\Users\dguitron\Documents\Belize and Sam Project\Class 1\[run_10296500.xlsm]dashboard'!E19"
[Class1!E8] = [Class1!E8].Value         


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken only the end part of your code seems to relate to your question. In which case you simply need to change the workbook name in each reference as follows.

```
[Class1!E6].Formula = "='C:\Users\dguitron\Documents\Belize and Sam Project\Class 1\[run_10296500.xlsm]dashboard'!E17"
[Class1!E6] = [Class1!E6].Value        

[Class1!E7].Formula = "='C:\Users\dguitron\Documents\Belize and Sam Project\Class 1\[run_10296501.xlsm]dashboard'!E17"
[Class1!E7] = [Class1!E7].Value         

[Class1!E8].Formula = "='C:\Users\dguitron\Documents\Belize and Sam Project\Class 1\[run_10296502.xlsm]dashboard'!E17"
[Class1!E8] = [Class1!E8].Value
```

Obviously I don't know the name of your other workbooks so I've just incrementes the last digit. If you want to make this a bit slicker then you could create an array of workbook names or use a counter with a For loop to cut down on the repitition but we would need to know more about your workbook naming convention to assist any further.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing for that part, but then I would have to also change the column. So for this gage all went in column E but for the next gage station it would have to go in F. Is there an easier way to automatically go to the next column?

Comment: @DaisyGuitron Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13985060/470014) question.