# Preventing duplicate entries in multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using this macro to prevent users from entering similar entries within a spreadsheet. This is working fine in a single column.

But how can I add similar in multiple columns (like Column A, D and F). Each column as to allow only unique records only. Please help me out

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Column <> 1 Or .Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(.Column), .Value) > 1 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .ClearContents
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            MsgBox "Record no. already exists!"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you can refer to this : Excel VBA Loop on columns
 at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985060/excel-vba-loop-on-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply this code to an additional column just by changing your `if` statement in your original code and allow another column

```
If (.Column <> 1 And .Column <> 4) Or .Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

more columns can be added with additional And statements And `.Column <> xxx`

```
If (.Column <> 1 And .Column <> 4 And .Column <> 6) Or .Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code within if and put in separate procedure in normal module:

```
Sub ClearCont(cl As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    cl.ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Record no. already exists!"
    'cl.Select
End Sub
```

Then, the code under worksheet should be like that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim col As Range

    With Target.Parent
        Set rng = Union(.Columns(1), .Columns(4), .Columns(6))
    End With


    With Target
        For Each col In rng.Columns
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(col, .Value) > 0 And col.Column <> .Column Then
                ClearCont Target
            ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountIf(col, .Value) > 1 Then
                ClearCont Target
            End If
        Next col
    End With
End Sub
```

The expression

```
Set rng = Union(.Columns(1), Columns(4), Columns(6))
```

chooses columns A, D and F, you can modify it to add more columns.

EDIT: As Peh below suggested, I have changed `ActiveSheet` to `Target.Parent`. I have also outcommented `cl.Select` in the `ClearCont` subroutine. I think this line of code would be useful if values are typed by hand directly in the worksheet - the user would be returned to the questioned cell. However, if values are entered by form for example, you would rather leave it out commented or delete it.

Comment: `ActiveSheet` is no good idea this can be a different sheet. Use `Target.Parent` to get the sheet where `Target` is in. Also `cl.Select` should be avoided.

Comment: Usually Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) works on active sheet. You need put special effort to modify non-active sheet.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you e.g. run a VBA macro that changes something eg on Sheet1 then still Sheet2 can be the active one. Therefore I just suggest to replace `ActiveSheet` with `Target.Parent` which fixes this issue easily and you won't run into any odd issues. Or remove the `With ActiveSheet` because then `.Columns` always refers to `Target.Parent` by default within the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: ok, I get your point. But I would consider cl.select in the first macro, depending on how the spreadsheet will be used. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, in this case `.Select` can make sense I just didn't see how that could be useful at first.