# Using WorksheetFunction with altering column and row numbers

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

My question is about VBA syntax/concept: I want to create a list using a for loop with a formula which changes column-input in accordance with the loop-function.

Closest I could find: [Excel VBA Loop on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985060/excel-vba-loop-on-columns)

The specific one I try extracts the "first not-NA()"-index position in the column (t, u, v ..., i.e. C6, C7, C8 relative to column N where I want my results).

The wanted result is that this code should be run by a single expression in a for loop:

```vb
Range("N109").Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(R[-103]C[6]:R[3769]C[6]<>0,),0)"
Range("N110").Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(R[-104]C[7]:R[3768]C[7]<>0,),0)"
Range("N111").Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(R[-105]C[8]:R[3767]C[8]<>0,),0)"
...
```

My attempt:

```vb
For i = 1 To 40
    Dim x, y, z As Variant '(or Integer, neither works)
        x = -102 - i
        y = 5 + i
        z = 3770 - i

Range("N" & (108 + i)).Select

'A1 and A2 are two different attempts to make this work
A1:    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(R[x]C[y]:R[z]C[y]<>0,),0)"
A2:    ActiveCell.value = WorksheetFunction.Match(TRUE,INDEX(R[x]C[y]:R[z]C[y]<>0,),0)"
```

I tried (outside of for loop), to write one of the ranges directly into the function, however this gives an error code.

```
A3:    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(Range("T6:T3878"))<>0,),0)"
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for bad key words, was thinking of: "Formula2R1C1"; "WorksheetFunction"; "For-loop", but I wasn't allowed...

Comment: Another option is to use column letter and row numbers, where column letters easily could be written with a for loop using this one:
"letter"=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,Cell-ID,4),"1","") (explained here: https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-column-number-to-letter)

Then it would only be necessary to put each result like: a= "letter" & (row+i), where "letter" already is a function of i...

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply variables inside of a FormulaR1C1 you have to write it in a particular way such as :

```
R[" & x & "]C[" & y & "]
```

I hope this can help you,

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I guess I didn't completely understand, since that did not work. I have added a screenshot edited into the last line of the main text (couldn't reply here with a screenshot)...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am not so familiar with the syntax for "relative refering", so I didn't get your suggestion Lucas to work, I guess I made more mistakes...
However, I have now  used "absolute, cellwise" reference system instead (which I now have learned syntax for):

```
Sub Get_position_of_first_non_NA_value()
Dim srNum, NumOfSeries As Integer
Dim strCellRange As String
NumOfSeries=Range("J106")
For srNum = 1 To NumOfSeries
    strCellRange = Range(Cells(7, 26 + srNum), Cells(2407, 26 + srNum)).Address
    Range("k" & (124 + srNum)).Formula2 = "=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(" & strCellRange & ">0,),0)" 'The
   '[ ">0,) ]-part can be switched with e.g. [ "<150,) ], if you want first value under 150, which is not NA()...
Next
End Sub
```